# NoClassDefFoundError when running test via Ant but working when Deployed in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, junit, ant

I am getting NoClassDefFoundError when I run via ant but it is working when I deployed the app in tomcat.

I invoke it using

```
ant test
```

Exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSource
at com.x.ws.repo.DatabaseConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.x.ws.repo.DatabaseConnection.getSynchronizedInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.x.ws.repo.DatabaseConnection.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.x.ws.repo.Foo.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.x.ws.repo.FooTest.setUp(Unknown Source)
```

Ant script

```
<path id="classpath.test">
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/junit-4.11.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hamcrest-all-1.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/java-json.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${main.build.dir}"/>
</path>

<target name="test-compile" depends="compile">
    <javac srcdir="${test.src.dir}" destdir="${test.build.dir}">
        <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
        <classpath refid="classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="test" depends="test-compile">
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no">
        <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
        <classpath location="${test.build.dir}" />

        <formatter type="xml" />
        <formatter type="plain" />
        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reports.src.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}">
                <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess DBCP is currently packaged in your ${CATALINA_HOME}/lib, i.e. the lib directory of Tomcat. The data source defined in the code run by `FooTest` must be defined as a `BasicDataSource`, so you should add another entry for `commons-dbcp.jar` in `classpath.test`.